# Removing a commit from the contributors list on Github

Tags: git, github

So, I messed up. I accidentally committed the `node_modules` file to my remote repo on Github. It wasn't a big deal practically because I just removed the file in the next commit, no harm no foul.

But now my contributor page looks god awful, example:

[image]

I'd like to go back and remove the culprit commit that is causing this travesty.

#### GIT Context:

The problem commit is the very first one of the project. Should I try to remove this commit? and if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get yourself on the commit where you deleted the file (second commit on the branch, if I understood correctly). `git checkout --orphan somebranch`. Then commit... that will create a "new" revision with no parent..... then you can drop the branch that is messed up and rename your current branch to whatever you like (consider cherry-picking the other revisions if you did more work on the broken branch).